# Will a user control be correctly disposed if it contains a control within an other object?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

The scenario is as follows and since I am (very) new to actually disposing my resources, I am not completely sure if it will work in my example.
Here the basic scenario which is really simplified for demonstration:

I have a user control `MyUserControl`, which contains a `scrollViewer`. Also I have a class `MyClass` that contains a `grid` and a `tabItem` and the UI has a `tabControl` and everything will at some point be connected as follows in `MainWindow`:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();

private void SomeMethod(TabItem tabItem)
    {
        MyUserControl uc = new MyUserControl();

        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        list.Add(mc);
        mc.tabItem = tabItem;
        tabItem.Content = uc;

        uc.scrollViewer.Content = mc.grid; 

        tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
        tabControl.SelectedItem = tabItem;
    }
```

Now at some point I want to remove the tabItem again and with that I want to free the resources of `uc` but I will not necessarily remove `mc` from `list`.
Is it enough to remove `tabItem` from `tabControl` and set `mc.tabItem = null`?

Comment: Why do you care about freeing the resources exactly?

Comment: Honestly, to have a nice clean program that doesn't occupy resources it won't use.
The user can add new `tabItems` where each item will contain a user control but the tab items can also be removed again, so I want to release the resources. I thought it's pretty normal to do that.

Comment: The Garbage Collector will release unused memory for you without any interaction. It is not a normal thing to do garbage collection yourself.

Comment: Well the garbage collector will not release memory that is still referenced somewhere, so the question is if in my example `uc` will be released.

Comment: Learn MVVM and let WPF manage the UI (instead of this horrible approach of manipulating UI elements in procedural code) and you will never have to worry about this again.

Comment: Thank you I will look into it and might change my approach (which I have a for a very good reason), but I would still appreciate an actual answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from that what you are building here is really not the way to go, just to answer your question:

As long as 'list' contains 'mc' and 'mc' holds a reference to 'tabItem' and 'tabItem' holds a reference to 'uc', 'uc' will not get garbage collected. It doesn't matter whether 'tabItem' is still in 'tabControl'.

If you set mc.tabItem to null, there is no more reference to uc and uc will get garbage collected. So, you get a **Yes** for your question. And, to be academic, it would be enough to set `tabItem.Content` to null.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the approach here seems very "dirty" but as I stated the whole problem is much more complicated and in this case it is not only up to me to change it, so actually I need to stick to this approach.

Comment: Fair enough, you know best. Keep it up!